# How to configure data being used by angularjs ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When data is configured for angularjs like this:

```
array = {"0":{"type":"Rocker","price":51},"1":"type":"Car","price":26900}};
```

The data will load into the HTML, but I can **NOT** sort or filter it.

If I configure the data like this:

```
array = [{"type":"Rocker","price":51},"type":"Car","price":26900}];
```

The data will load into the HTML, and I **CAN** sort and filter it.

I manually changed the data to get it to work.  But I need code to convert the data.

How do I convert the multi-dimensional array:

`{key:{array},key:{array}}`

to an array structure of:

`[{array}, {array}]`

so that angularjs will sort and filter my data?

### Here is what I have tried for code:

```
myControllers.controller('processData',
function getAndProcessData($scope) {
  //Get JSON data as string from a DIV element
  var storeData = document.getElementById('idStoreData').textContent;
  console.log('storeData Before JSON: ' + storeData);

  //Convert the string to JSON
  storeData = JSON.parse(storeData);
  console.log('storeData After: ' + storeData);

  //Create an array object.
  var valueForStore = [];

  for (var storeKeyName in storeData) {
    console.log("storeKeyName: " + storeKeyName); 
    console.log('Each loop field: ' + storeData[storeKeyName]);

    valueForStore = valueForStore + storeData[storeKeyName];
  };

  //The variable "storeItemsData" is used by ng-repeat
  $scope.storeItemsData = valueForStore;

};
```

When I use the above code I get the error:

> *Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http/errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=entry%20in%20storeItemsData%20%7C%20filter%3Aentry%20%7C%20orderBy%3AstoreOrderProp&*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most of the way there, the only problem I can see with the above code is this line:

```
valueForStore = valueForStore + storeData[storeKeyName];
```

I think you're trying to append an item to the array, in which case, the statement should be

```
valueForStore.push(storeData[storeKeyName]);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
valueForStore = valueForStore + storeData[storeKeyName];
```

should be

```
valueForStore.push( storeData[storeKeyName]);
```